# MySQL InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 5852 in file trx0purge.cc line 699

Tags: mysql, assertion

Can anyone help with this?  My computer shut off, and when I turned it back on, my server starts and then stops immediately.  I was able to get this error log file:

```
2013-08-01 11:44:15 1064 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 38903730
2013-08-01 11:44:15 1064 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-08-01 11:44:15 1064 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-08-01 11:44:15 1064 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-08-01 11:44:15 1064 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-08-01 11:47:48 9b4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 111.0M
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2462951 and 2462951 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 38903740 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-08-01 11:47:48 1600 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2013-08-01 11:48:04 1600 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-08-01 11:48:04 1600 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-08-01 11:48:04 16dc  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 5852 in file trx0purge.cc line 699
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->iter.trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg->last_trx_no
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same issue and can't find a thing on Google.